# Every Attempt at Error Handling Fails with GET

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, error-handling

UPDATED (12.3.2019)

I'm using MySQL 8.x and every attempt at putting any error handling that provides internal details fails on the "GET" (red highlight) stating:

```
GET is not valid at this position
```

I've simplified this issue further and have created the below code which executes without any issue in the MySQL Workbench Query Window:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS routine1;
CREATE PROCEDURE routine1 ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        SET @full_error = CONCAT('SQL Exception:act_account_main_create:(', @p1, ') ', @p2);
        SELECT @full_error;
    END;
END$$
```

However if I try to use this in an actual routine (note this includes double-clicking the "add routine" option in Workbench and just placing the code inside the BEGIN section), MySQL Workbench gives me the exact same error on GET, as seen in the below code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE routine1 ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    BEGIN 
        GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @p1 = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @p2 = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        SET @full_error = CONCAT('SQL Exception:act_account_main_create:(', @p1, ') ', @p2);
        SELECT @full_error;
    END;
END
```

Note this is in a database model that has dozens of functional routines (all working in a live database).

Also note using ANY of the code samples from the official documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/get-diagnostics.html) (cut & paste entire routine or just the GET selection within a new routine) results in the exact same failure on GET.

[image: Here's a picture of the error]

Comment: Does it work if you create the procedure using the `mysql` command line client?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well given it works in the Query window, I would think so. Note I just updated the body. I'm wondering if this is some sort of bug.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been confirmed as a bug associated with the workbench file. While the exact cause is not known, exporting and importing into a new workbench file resolves the issue. This bug has been reported to Oracle.